# Use buttons to send data of a table row to a server. I am using Datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I want to have a custom button which sends a selected table row data to my server .

Which method / function should I use inside Javascript to send the data to my server(servlet)?

```js
buttons:[{
  text: 'Send',
  action: function () {
    var oid = $.map(table.rows({selected:true}).data(), function (item) {
      return item[3]
    });
    var appby = $.map(table.rows({selected:true}).data(), function (item) {
      return item[2]
    });
    var odt = $.map(table.rows({selected:true}).data(), function (item) {
      return item[1]
    });
    var cname = $.map(table.rows({selected:true}).data(), function (item) {
      return item[4]
    });
    var cno = $.map(table.rows({selected:true}).data(), function (item) {
      return item[5]
    });
    alert(cno+" "+cname);
  }
}],
```

I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: Axois or Fetch?

Comment: Since you are using DataTables, that means you are already using jQuery on that web page. So you can use the jQuery [`ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. The documentation has examples - and there are lots of other tutorials on the web. If you get stuck you can ask a more specific question (assuming it has not already been asked and answered).